# can't get a method from child class from my parent class array

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

I make my parent class into an array, but it will not let me use the methods from my child class through that same array. It want to be able to make only one array, but be able to use all the methods from both classes.

```
public static void main (String args[])
Book[] bk = new Book[5];

class Book{

    private String title;

    public String getTitle(){
    return title;}
//rest of code for class
}

class EBook extends Book {

    private String website;

    public EBook (String title, String website)//more the just these two but you get the idea
    {
        super(title);
        setWebsite(website);}

    public String getWebsite (){
        return website;}
//rest of code for class
}
```

Now whenever I type something like bk.getWebsite in the main method, Eclipse is giving me an error. It says that I have to create the method in the Book class first. Is there anything that I can do to get around this besides creating another array, or is that the only option?

Comment: *What* error is it giving you?  I can see at least four (all syntax).

Comment: Are you asking why you can't use methods from `EBook` when you've created an array of type `Book`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to call methods specific to subclasses you need to add a cast:

```
if (bk[i] instanceof EBook) {
    String website=((EBook)bk[i]).getWebsite();
}
```

Note that checking the type like this is suboptimal. One should prefer putting methods in the base class, and calling an override from subclass, or using double dispatch (e.g. through visitor pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Book has no Constructor with element String.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call Book.getWebsite() where you want to call EBook.getWebsite(). In order to do this you have to cast it to EBook first.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an error perhaps because the getWebsite() method is not defined in the parent Book class.

If you want the parent to be able to call the child method then if possible you can consider to have the Book class as an abstract class and define a getWebsite() abstract method and implement the getWebsite method in Ebook.

Now when you have a Book instance with a Ebook implmentation, you will be able to call the getWebsite method implemented in Ebook class via the Book instance.

You can find more information regarding Abstract methods and classes here [Oracle docs Abstract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)